# env helper returns null even if providing default value

Tags: laravel

Inside my `.env` I got these two

```
ATLAS_RELEASES=null
ATLAS_DOWNLOAD=null
```

Inside my own config file I have this

```
    'releases_url' => env('ATLAS_RELEASES', $baseUrl . 'atlas/raw/master/releases.json'),
    'download_url' => env('ATLAS_DOWNLOAD', $baseUrl . 'atlas/releases/download'),
```

Once some code runs, that uses

```
    $relasesUrl = config('releases_url');
    $downloadUrl = config('download_url');
```

`null` is returned instead of the second option, which I've specified in the config file. Since I'm not using `.env` outside of config files, I wonder why I get this behavior?

The above only works if I remove these two completely from the `.env` file

```
ATLAS_RELEASES
ATLAS_DOWNLOAD
```

Any ideas why this strange behavior happens?

Comment: you have to use config(filename.propertyname)

Comment: I do use it, I removed it by mistake, assume it is there since everything works if I remove the ENV variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the key exists in the `.env` file no matter if if is null or no value at all, that one will be used.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration

> The second value passed to the env function is the "default value". **This value will be used if no environment variable exists for the given key.**

Comment: if ENV_VALUE=null, does that count as existing? That is my current issue

Comment: @niko yes it does, null is value as well

Comment: @nikocraft even empty, will still be used. So remember, as long as the KEY exists in `.env` file no matter if it does or does not contain any value, null, empty, whatever, that will be used.

Comment: thanks, I've marked your answer as the correct one! Cheers, buddy!